# webdriver.io process out of memory - how to increase memory space size similar to node --max_old_space_size=2048

Tags: webdriver-io

I am getting following error while running my test using webdriver.io. After analysis I realized that I need to increase memory space. However not sure how to do it with webdriver.io. In node i know its done using `node --max_old_space_size=2048`.

How to do same with webdriver.io?

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

 9251010 ms: Mark-sweep 1352.8 (1458.1) -> 1352.7 (1458.1) MB, 2938.1 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
 9253943 ms: Mark-sweep 1352.7 (1458.1) -> 1352.8 (1458.1) MB, 2932.4 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
 9256877 ms: Mark-sweep 1352.8 (1458.1) -> 1352.1 (1457.1) MB, 2934.5 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
 9259812 ms: Mark-sweep 1352.1 (1457.1) -> 1298.1 (1458.1) MB, 2935.1 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x3faa6f6e3ac1 <JS Object>
    1: DefineObjectProperty [native v8natives.js:~464] [pc=0x3524a7536435] (this=0x39f056913eb9 <JS Global Object>,K=0x1ebe9c167ff1 <an Object with map 0x107d9d0fff21>,W=0x3cc73ab4c6d9 <String[7]: strings>,H=0x1ebe9c164fb9 <a PropertyDescriptor with map 0x1ae8ebfa37a1>,Z=0x3faa6f604231 <true>)
    2: DefineOwnProperty [native v8natives.js:~633] [pc=0x3524a6c8a597] (this=0x39f056913eb9 <JS Globa...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think that it´s webdriver.io related problem because first you can´t find anything if you search memory settings and second thing is the main program is node this means you need to edit those hardware settings only for node.js

Did you try
    --max_new_space_size

What did you do with your script that you got memory error, please send code.Are you reading some huge data? Also you use node --max_old_space_size=2048 why not increase to 4096. Or may this can help
    --max_old_space_size=4096 --optimize_for_size --max_executable_size=4096 --stack_size=4096

Comment: Yaa, the problem was not related to webdriver.io. After going through docs, I realized I can use `execArgv:['--max_old_space_size=5120']` in `wdio.conf.js` to allocate more memory to node js process. This helped me to increase memory space. But the real reason was mutating object on a function call. Yes, I do read huge data which was leading huge size of the object and then out of memory issue. After I changed my code to not to mutate and simply return expected object then overall it's more stable.

Comment: ah cool dude nice 2 know :). The thing is most people have 16gb ram in pc or they use vps/root server in combination with node.js - This is a really big problem if you have low memory in your old pc haha^^ But try to chunk everything is always an alternative.